# Need clarification on Ruby logical operators

Tags: ruby, logical-operators

Recently I started learning Ruby. I am practicing logical operators in `irb` and I got these results, which I don't understand. Can you please clarify these examples for me?

```
1 and 0
#=> 0 

0 and 1
#=> 1 

0 && 1
#=> 1
```

Comment: here's a really good explanation of this: http://devblog.avdi.org/2014/08/26/how-to-use-rubys-english-andor-operators-without-going-nuts/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As opposed to other languages like C, in Ruby all values except for `nil` and `false` are considered “truthy”. This means, that all these values behave like `true` in the context of a boolean expression.

Ruby's boolean operators will *not* return `true` or `false`. Instead, they return the first operand that causes the evaluation of the condition to be complete (also known as [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)). For boolean *and* that means, it will either return the first “falsy” operand or the last one:

```
false && 1    # => false     (falsy)
nil   && 1    # => nil       (falsy)
false && nil  # => false     (falsy)
1     && 2    # => 2         (truthy)
```

For boolean *or* that means, it will either return the first “truthy” operand or the last one:

```
false || 1    # => 1         (truthy)
nil   || 1    # => 1         (truthy)
false || nil  # => nil       (falsy)
1     || 2    # => 1         (truthy)
```

This allows for some interesting constructs. It is a very common pattern to use `||` to set default values, for example:

```
def hello(name)
  name = name || 'generic humanoid'
  puts "Hello, #{name}!"
end

hello(nil)    # Hello, generic humanoid!
hello('Bob')  # Hello, Bob!
```

Another similar way to acheive the same thing is

```
name || (name = 'generic humanoid')
```

With the added benefit that if name is truthy, no assignment is performed at all. There is even a shortcut for this assignment of default values:

```
name ||= 'generic humanoid'
```

If you paid careful attention you will have noticed that this may cause some trouble, if one valid value is `false`:

```
destroy_humans = nil
destroy_humans ||= true
destroy_humans
#=> true

destroy_humans = false
destroy_humans ||= true
destroy_humans
#=> true, OMG run!
```

This is rarely the desired effect. So if you know that the values can only be a `String` or `nil`, using `||` and `||=` is fine. If the variable can be `false`, you have to be more verbose:

```
destroy_humans = nil
destroy_humans = true if destroy_humans.nil?
destroy_humans
#=> true

destroy_humans = false
destroy_humans = true if destroy_humans.nil?
destroy_humans
#=> false, extinction of humanity digressed!
```

That was close! But wait, there is another caveat – specifically with the usage of `and` and `or`. These should ***never*** be used for boolean expressions, because they have [very low operator precedence](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html). That means they will be evaluated last. Consider the following examples:

```
is_human = true
is_zombie = false
destroy_human = is_human && is_zombie
destroy_human
#=> false

is_human = true
is_zombie = false
destroy_human = is_human and is_zombie
destroy_human
#=> true, Waaaah but I'm not a zombie!
```

Let me add some parentheses to clarify what's happening here:

```
destroy_human = is_human && is_zombie
# equivalent to
destroy_human = (is_human && is_zombie)

destroy_human = is_human and is_zombie
# equivalent to
(destroy_human = is_human) and is_zombie
```

So `and` and or are really just useful as “control-flow operators”, for example:

```
join_roboparty or fail 'forever alone :('
# this will raise a RuntimeError when join_roboparty returns a falsy value

join_roboparty and puts 'robotz party hard :)'
# this will only output the message if join_roboparty returns a truthy value
```

I hope that clarifies everything you need to know about these operators. It takes a bit of getting used to, because it differs from the way other languages handle it. But once you know how to use the different options, you've got some powerful tools at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Both values are 'truthy' (in Ruby everything that isn't `nil` or `false` is truthy), so in all cases the second value is returned. On the contrary, if you use 'or', first value will be returned:

```
1 || 0 #=> 1
0 || 1 #=> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby both `0` and `1` is truth value. (Only `nil` and `false` are false value)

If both operands are truth value, `and`, `&&` returns the last value.